# Use of the macbook-air tag and the macbook-pro tag instead of the macbook tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that we should use the [macbook-air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air) tag and the [macbook-pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro) tag instead of the [macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook) tag if the question is Macbook-Air or Macbook-pro specific, since Macbooks are discontinued.

I spent some time retagging questions that are from [macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook) to [macbook-pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro)/[macbook-air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air).  But I decided to ask "Is it right to do this?" before going any further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think we should be able to have a minimum of **two levels** of details, with the brand also added *only if needed for clarity*.  An exception, for use of additional sub-tag, should only made for unusual sub-classes of existing complex tags.

---

**Argument 1: *Search***

If a question is raised, it should be possible to find other similar questions (and answers). As there is no control of style or approach to question wording, this is best achieved by informed individuals setting (or correcting) the **tags** associated.

> ***Minor Rant:** It is not overly useful when someone removes tags (or complete definitions) when they either don't understand the issue
>   being discussed or the effort required to find (and re-tag) questions
>   in the first place.*

---

**Argument 2: *Change***

We need to clearly differentiate (sometimes rapid) changing use of technology: use of ARM (vs x86), netbook (**limited** screen height), and smartphone (**small** 4" screen), tablet (7", 10" screen), Unity (vs Gnome), touch (vs. mouse), multi-touch, etc.

All of these factors are critical IMHO factors to the aim of **Ubuntu** being able to smoothly adapt to running on everything from smartphone, desktop, server, thin-client, tablet, to cloud.

---

some examples: (*that I have used/seen in last two weeks*)

- **dell-inspiron** - (Dell laptops w/ Intel Core; **fairly generic**)
- **hp-microserver-36l** - (HP micro-tower server, (older) 36L series)
- **hp-microserver-40l** - (HP micro-tower server, (current) 40L series)
- *hp-proliant* **X** - (HP 'branded' servers; **too generic**)
- **hp-proliant-ml** - (HP tower servers)
- **hp-proliant-dl** - (HP rack-based servers)
- **hp-proliant-bl** - (HP blade-based technology)
- **iphone-4s** - (Apple, iPhone 4S smartphone, iOS)
- **iphone-5** - (Apple, iPhone 5 smartphone, iOS)
- **galaxy-S-duos** - (Samsung 4" dual-SIM Android smartphone, series S)
- **galaxy-s3** - (Samsung 4.8" Android smartphone, series S III)
- **galaxy-s3-4g** - (Samsung S III, with 4G/LTE)
- **galaxy-s3-mini** - (Samsung 4" Android smartphone, series S III)
- **galaxy-tab-7** - (Samsung 7" Android tablet, (older) Tab series)
- **galaxy-tab-7.7** - (Samsung 7.7" Android tablet, Tab+ series)
- **galaxy-tab2-7** - (Samsung 7" Android tablet, (current) Tab 2 series)
- **galaxy-tab2-10** - (Samsung 10.1" Android tablet, Tab 2 series)
- **laserjet-1500** - (HP LaserJet 10xx/15xx family)
- **macbook-air** - (Apple, ultra-thin laptop)
- **mac-mini-3** - (Apple, tiny form-factor PC, series 3)
- *google-nexus* **X** - (Google/ASUS phone, Android smartphone OR tablet; **too generic**)
- **nexus-4** - (Google/ASUS, 4" Android smartphone)
- **nexus-7** - (Google/ASUS, 7" Android tablet)
- **nexus-10** - (Google/ASUS, 10" Android tablet)
- **samsung-series9** - (Samsung, ultra-thin laptop, 9 series)

Answer (score 7):

They are all from [apple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apple) and are all [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac).

Should we also have tags like the following?

[power-macintosh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-macintosh)
[imac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac)
[imac-g3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-g3)
[imac-g4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-g4)
[imac-g5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-g5)
[emac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emac)
[imac-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-core)
[imac-core-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-core-2)
[imac-core-i5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-core-i5)
[imac-core-i7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imac-core-i7)
[mac-pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro)
[powerbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/powerbook)
[powerbook-g3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/powerbook-g3)
[ibook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ibook)
[powerbook-g4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/powerbook-g4)
[macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook)
[macbook-pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro)
[macbook-air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air)
[macbook-aluminum-unibody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-aluminum-unibody)
[macbook-pro-aluminum-unibody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro-aluminum-unibody)
[xserve-g4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xserve-g4)
[xserve-g5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xserve-g5)
[intel-xserve](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-xserve)
[power-mac-g4-cube](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-mac-g4-cube)
[mac-mini](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini)
[mac-mini-g4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini-g4)
[mac-mini-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini-core)
[mac-mini-core-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini-core-2)

To differentiate *all* the different mac/apple products?

I don't think so.

Comment: I would second the thought that despite driver differences required for Air vs Pro vs iMac, for grouping it would be better to have fewer tags for Mac hardware. Personally, I would merge and place a synonym from macintosh -> mac and then try synonyms on the rest and see how it goes in practice for several months.

Answer (score 6):

Just my opinion, not a great idea.  I understand that it's a specific model from Mac.  But we do have a Dell tag (manufacturer), and a Dell-Inspiron tag (model family), but not a Dell-Inspiron-XXXX tag (specific model).  I don't think it needs to get subdivided any further.

Also, I'm not entirely sure we should have it divided further than dell/mac.  Inspiron is pushing it.

Comment: While I generally agree, I have to point out that a MacBook Air is *very* different from a MacBook Pro when it comes to hardware.

Comment: @jrg Fair point