# Do we need a tag for every Apple product?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was editing a Mac related question, and noticed we had a [macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook), [mackbookpro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mackbookpro), [macbookair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbookair) and [mac-mini](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) tags.

Do we really need all these tags for Apple products?  I'm not sure anything needs to be done about this, but I want to know what other people think.

Are Apple products *that* different?

Comment: macbook, macbookpro and macbookair are very, very different machines with very, very different hardware.

Comment: I disagree.  Most Apple hardware has the same type of CPU, Graphics and Network Controller.  I only see two graphics cards between all models of the Macbook Pro, Mac Mini and Macbook Air.  They also each have a Intel Core i3, i5 or i7 processor.

Comment: @jrg You forgot the sarcasm sign, right?!

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3604/use-of-the-macbook-air-tag-and-the-macbook-pro-tag-instead-of-the-macbook-tag/5338#5338

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend we make [macbookpro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) and [macbookair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbookair) synonyms of [macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/macbook).

[mac-mini](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) is sufficiently different as to warrant its own separate tag, at least going by the tags we've allowed to exist long-term for other manufacturers.

Of course, [ipad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ipad) is totally different from the above, though we might want another question to discuss if [ipad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ipad) and [ipod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ipod) should really be different tags.

Comment: Actually, since the Macbook has been discontinued, I think we should make them all synonyms [tag:macbookpro].

Comment: @Seth Technicality... they both start with "macbook" whether or not they end in air or pro, lets not buy into their marketing.

Comment: @Seth Also, there's no telling what the next MacBook will be called. I recommend against progressively changing a tag every time what models are available changes.

Comment: @mateo_salta @ Eliah You guys have convinced me. Lets make them synonyms of [tag:macbook].

Comment: Also the next Macbook will the the "Macbook Air S" of course!

Comment: or they will call it iMacBook Pro Retina Or *The New MacBook*

Comment: lol, of course!  Also, about the [tag:ipad] and [tag:ipod], the iPad and iPod are *very* different devices and each deserve there own tag, though I wouldn't support an "iPod Touch" tag.